# Remove quotation marks whitespaces from string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'd like to remove quotation marks whitespace from string, in my case, change `' FIGUEIRAS040C '` by `'FIGUEIRAS040C'`:

```
my.ex<- "SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = ' FIGUEIRAS040C '"
```

and output needs to be:

```
my.ex
[1] "SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = 'FIGUEIRAS040C'"
```

I try to `str_pad()` function and `regex` expressions without success. Please, any help to solve it?

Comment: Do you know how that string was created in the first place? It may be easier to fix it there rather than clean it up after the fact.

Comment: Agree with MrFlick, if `ID_UNIQUE` is coming from a data frame for example, you can just run `trimws` on the column to fix this output.

Comment: Unfurtunally `ID_UNIQUE`came for a loop (`paste("SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE =","'",var0,"'"))`.

Comment: Don't form queries like that, it's prone to many problems (such as this). It's typically much better to use bound-parameters or `glue::glue_sql`; see https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/.

Comment: But to fix *this **symptom***, either change from `paste` to `paste0`, or use `paste(..., sep="")` (effectively identical). But really, doing it that way has many risks, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans problem solved with our solution: `sqlInput <- glue_sql("SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = '",var0,"'")`

Comment: Nope, you missed the point. Use `glue_sql`'s use of `{var0}` mid string, likely `glue::glue_sql("SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = {var0}", .con=dbconn)`. The issue against the use of `paste` to add *data* into a query is based on issues with escaping quotes (single/double), and your use of `glue("select ...'", var0, "'")` is maintaining that mistake.

Comment: Really, I strongly encourage you to read that link and internalize **Parameterized queries** and **Using glue_sql()** ... future-you will thank present-you, it is well worth the short time investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Match a quote, any amount of spaces ( `*`), the shortest string (`.*?`) of any characters until another amount of spaces ( `*`) and a quote.  Replace that with the part between the spaces and surround it with quotes.  Use gsub instead of sub if there can be more than one.  No packages are used.

```
sub("' *(.*?) *'", "'\\1'", my.ex)
## [1] "SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = 'FIGUEIRAS040C'"
```

**2)** This approach works with SQLite and may work with whatever dialect of SQL you are using if it supports a `trim` function.

```
sub("('.*?')", "trim(\\1)", my.ex)
## [1] "SELECT * FROM CF_2021 WHERE ID_UNIQUE = trim(' FIGUEIRAS040C ')"
```

For example,

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "select * from iris where Species = ' setosa ' limit 3"
sql2 <- sub("('.*?')", "trim(\\1)", sql)

sql2
## [1] "select * from iris where Species = trim(' setosa ') limit 3"

sqldf(sql2)
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```